# (Kivy) How to address a specific button in a menu?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, layout, kivy

I am trying to change only the attributes of one of these buttons in kivy (python). Say I want to change the background of the first button, how would I reference only it? I am very new to python so I'm not sure how to go about naming the different buttons individually so that I can then go back and reference them individually. Help appreciated!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import VariableListProperty

presentation = Builder.load_file("app.kv")

class myApp(Widget):

    pass

class LandingScreen(GridLayout):
    def build(self):
        return presentation
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 5
        Color(.5, .5, .5, 1)
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 2'))


class myTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
      return LandingScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myTestApp().run()
```

Kv file:

```
<GridLayout>:
    height: 600
    width: 800
    spacing: 25
    padding: 25,25
```

Comment: While not solving your problem you can also add widgets in a loop, i.e. `for i in range(20): self.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))` to reduce code repition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'd want to write out all the buttons manually or give them an id yourself (what do we do with 200 widgets..?)
You can keep references to all your buttons in a list or a dictionary, and change them when you see fit:

```
class LandingScreen(GridLayout):
    def build(self):
        return presentation
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 5
        Color(.5, .5, .5, 1)

        self.buttons = [] #we will add references to all buttons here

        for x in range(20):
            self.buttons.append(Button(text='button ' + str(x))) #make a reference to the button before adding it in
            self.add_widget(self.buttons[x])

        self.buttons[0].background_color = (0,0.8,0,1) # changing only the first button from the list
```

Comment: You have helped me more than you could ever know! I don't know why I couldn't wrap my head around this but I've got it down now. Thanks.

Comment: If you were to want to add an image to the background instead, what would that look like? I'm trying to use source: "file.png" to no avail.

Comment: I'm glad I helped, for issues like this I'd suggest referring to the official documentation and/or fining example code. Other than that first make sure you have the correct path to the image (try just opening it for example), and make sure you are adding it to the `canvas` of the button instead of the button itself

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color using `background_color` atribute:

**In kv languaje:**

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.lang import Builder


    Builder.load_string('''
    <LandingScreen@GridLayout>:
        cols: 5
        height: 600
        width: 800
        spacing: 25
        padding: 25,25
        Button:
            text: 'Hello 1'
            background_color: (.5, .5, .5, 1)
        Button:
            text: 'Hello 1'
        Button:
            text: 'Hello 2'
        Button:
            text: 'World 2'
        Button:
            text: 'Hello 1'
        Button:
            text: 'World 1'
        Button:
            text: 'Hello 2'
        Button:
            text: 'World 2'
        Button:
            text: 'Hello 1'
        Button:
            text: 'World 1'
        Button:
            text: 'Hello 2'
        Button:
            text: 'World 2'
        Button:
            text: 'Hello 1'
        Button:
            text: 'World 1'
        Button:
            text: 'Hello 2'
        Button:
            text: 'World 2'
        Button:
            text: 'Hello 1'
        Button:
            text: 'World 1'
        Button:
            text: 'Hello 2'
        Button:
            text: 'World 2'    
    ''')

    class LandingScreen(GridLayout):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    class myTestApp(App):
        def build(self):
          return LandingScreen()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        myTestApp().run()
```

**In Python:**

```
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button



Builder.load_string('''
<LandingScreen@GridLayout>:
    cols: 5
    height: 600
    width: 800
    spacing: 25
    padding: 25,25

''')

class LandingScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1',  background_color = (.5, .5, .5, 1)))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='World 2'))

    def change_color(self,  instance):
        color = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random(),  1)
        self.btn1.background_color =  color


class myTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
      return LandingScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myTestApp().run()
```

If you need to reference the object at any time you can assign an `id` (kv-language) or assign a variable / attribute to the instance (Python).

You can use the `Id` in python using the `ids` attribute (dictionary). For example: `self.ids.btn1` or  `self.ids['btn1']`.

```
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder



Builder.load_string('''
<LandingScreen@GridLayout>:
    cols: 5
    height: 600
    width: 800
    spacing: 25
    padding: 25,25
    Button:
        id: btn1
        text: 'Hello 1'
        background_color: (.5, .5, .5, 1)
    Button:
        id: btn2
        text: 'Random color'
        on_press: root.change_color()

''')

class LandingScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def change_color(self):
        color = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random(),  1)
        self.ids.btn1.background_color =  color
        #self.ids['btn1'].background_color =  color

class myTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
      return LandingScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myTestApp().run()
```

In Python assign a variable / attribute to the instance and use it to reference the object:

```
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button



Builder.load_string('''
<LandingScreen@GridLayout>:
    cols: 5
    height: 600
    width: 800
    spacing: 25
    padding: 25,25

''')

class LandingScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.btn1 = Button(text = "Hello world!")
        self.btn2 = Button(text = "Random Color",  on_press= self.change_color)
        self.add_widget(self.btn1)
        self.add_widget(self.btn2)

    def change_color(self,  instance):
        color = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random(),  1)
        self.btn1.background_color =  color


class myTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
      return LandingScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myTestApp().run()
```